# Нажатие кнопки сквозь таблицу

Tags: libgdx, touch-event

Создаю кнопку в Group

```
menubutton = new Button(style);
    menubutton.setPosition(topbar.getX() + 910, topbar.getY() + 22);
    menubutton.setBounds(menubutton.getX(), menubutton.getY(), menubutton.getWidth(), menubutton.getPrefHeight());
    menubutton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            Gdx.app.log("Log", "Test");
        }
    });
    this.addActor(menubutton);
```

Затем там же создаю таблицу

```
table = new Table();
    table.setSize(1100, 600);
    table.setBackground(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bkgd.png")))));
    table.setPosition(90, 60);

    this.addActor(table);
```

Таблица перекрывает кнопку, но по нажатию в области таблицы на то место, за которым находится кнопка, происходит срабатывание события clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено путём установки задней группе .setTouchable(Touchable.disabled).